AWS ElasticBeanstalk Django collectstatic expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'
I'm using django-storages on elastic beanstalk and when i try to collectstatic i get this error.
Note that i can collectstatic with it fine on my local machine.
I have validated that all ENV vars are set fine.
2024-06-06 16:20:37,084 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
2024-06-06 16:20:37,084 P57299 [INFO]       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
2024-06-06 16:20:37,084 P57299 [INFO]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-06 16:20:37,085 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
2024-06-06 16:20:37,085 P57299 [INFO]       collected = self.collect()
2024-06-06 16:20:37,085 P57299 [INFO]                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-06 16:20:37,085 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 135, in collect
2024-06-06 16:20:37,085 P57299 [INFO]       handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
2024-06-06 16:20:37,085 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 368, in copy_file
2024-06-06 16:20:37,085 P57299 [INFO]       if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
2024-06-06 16:20:37,085 P57299 [INFO]              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-06 16:20:37,085 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 278, in delete_file
2024-06-06 16:20:37,085 P57299 [INFO]       if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
2024-06-06 16:20:37,086 P57299 [INFO]          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-06 16:20:37,086 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/storages/backends/s3.py", line 541, in exists
2024-06-06 16:20:37,086 P57299 [INFO]       self.connection.meta.client.head_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=name)
2024-06-06 16:20:37,086 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 565, in _api_call
2024-06-06 16:20:37,086 P57299 [INFO]       return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
2024-06-06 16:20:37,086 P57299 [INFO]              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-06 16:20:37,086 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 958, in _make_api_call
2024-06-06 16:20:37,086 P57299 [INFO]       api_params = self._emit_api_params(
2024-06-06 16:20:37,086 P57299 [INFO]                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-06 16:20:37,086 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1084, in _emit_api_params
2024-06-06 16:20:37,087 P57299 [INFO]       self.meta.events.emit(
2024-06-06 16:20:37,087 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 412, in emit
2024-06-06 16:20:37,087 P57299 [INFO]       return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
2024-06-06 16:20:37,087 P57299 [INFO]              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-06 16:20:37,087 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 256, in emit
2024-06-06 16:20:37,087 P57299 [INFO]       return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
2024-06-06 16:20:37,087 P57299 [INFO]              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-06 16:20:37,087 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
2024-06-06 16:20:37,087 P57299 [INFO]       response = handler(**kwargs)
2024-06-06 16:20:37,088 P57299 [INFO]                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-06 16:20:37,088 P57299 [INFO]     File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py", line 282, in validate_bucket_name
2024-06-06 16:20:37,088 P57299 [INFO]       if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):
2024-06-06 16:20:37,088 P57299 [INFO]              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-06-06 16:20:37,088 P57299 [INFO]   TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'

